# Actions on Google app generated two different User Ids for the same user account and same device

Tags: actions-on-google, google-home

Actions on Google app created two different user IDs for the Primary user.

I'm using the same device, same phone and app. The first time, it created an alphanumeric Id. The second time it created numeric Id.

This issue affected our user personalization.

Comment: Minor grammatical fixes and improvements.

Comment: Were both invocations done on a mobile device? Was the second (numeric) id like an epoch value (something like 1517991232) ?

Comment: @Nazeem - The skill is tested in Google home surface device. First time It generated the user id like "azdhdfhwlle7jhfdhj", the second user id generated like 15179991232.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**userId** isn't a very reliable way for customization as it's subject to change under certain circumstances like when your voice doesn't match on Google Home devices (Your case) or the user resets the app which generates a new userId  You can find more about user identity  [here](https://developers.google.com/actions/identity/user-info).

A better approach will be to use [account linking](https://developers.google.com/actions/identity/).